# Regex pattern returns null for variable as pattern

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I am reading regex pattern from a .txt file and passing it as a variable and using it to search in a very big text file. However, variable passing in regex search didnt work. My code snippet is

```
with open(r"C:\Desktop\list_pattern.txt", "r") as file1:
  for pattern in file1:
      with open(r'C:\Desktop\log.txt',"r") as my_file:
          for lines in my_file:
              k=re.search('{}'.format(pattern), lines)   # I even tried re.search(pattern, lines)            
              if k!=None:
                  print("k is",k)
```

For example, the first lne in list_pattern.txt is "Battery Low" and it gives 0 match in log.txt. However, if i replace the code line with `k=re.search('Battery Low', lines)`, it gives 12 match. Any idea what may be wrong? I am using python 3.10.

Comment: When you read from the file, each line has a leading newline character. Try `patter.strip()` instead of just `pattern`.

Comment: have you tried adding `print(pattern)` to make sure it's what you think it is?

Comment: @h4z3 you pinpointed the exact culprit ! Thanx a lot. it worked now.

Comment: @Chris, yes, checked, its string, no doubt, but as h4z3 mentioned, it got solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the file lines with `for lines in my_file:` the line break chars remain at the end of the `lines`. You need to use `pattern.rstrip()` to get rid of the trailing whitespace, or - if the patterns can end in menaingful whitespace, it is safer to use `.rstrip('\n')`. If you have no meaningful whitespace on both ends of each pattern, you can use `pattern.strip()`.

There seems to be no reason to use `str.format`, just use the pattern variable directly.

So you need to use

```py
k=re.search(pattern.rstrip('\n'), lines) 
# or if there can be no meaningful whitespace at the end of each pattern:
k=re.search(pattern.rstrip(), lines) 
# or if there can be no meaningful whitespace on both ends of each pattern:
k=re.search(pattern.strip(), lines)
```